# How to set up multitenant Route53 subdomains with parent domain not on Route53?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-route53

My goal is to be able to add/drop subdomains for a multi-tenant app via Route53: `tenant.example.com`. Account provisioning should place the new tenant on a hosting node and then add the newly onboarded tenant subdomain to Route53. The parent DNS is currently handled by a 3rd party (dnsmadeeasy). Currently DNS provider has something like this:

```
example.com -> A -> <someIP>
example.com -> MX -> <mailhost>
mail.example.com -> CNAME ->  <mailhost>
www.example.com -> CNAME -> example.com
example.com -> NS -> <several provider name servers>
```

I'm also pretty sure the DNS parent provider (dnsmadeeasy) has a SOA record too which is implicit (not shown in management UI). So I did the following:

- I added a wildcard hosted zone in Route53: `*.example.com`. This has 5 records right now, 4 NS records with various name servers and a SOA record
- I added the Route53 NS records to the parent DNS provider (dnsmadeeasy)

  `*.example.com -> NS -> <Route53 name server for hostzone above>`

My thinking was that now I can start adding A records in the Route53 zone for each tenant:

```
tenant1.example.com -> A -> <tenant1 hosting IP>
tenant2.example.com -> A -> <tenant1 hosting IP>
...
```

But trying to add A records in Route53 results in `tenant1.\052.example.com` which is not what I want. And I'm not even sure it will work.

My question is whether this is a correct way to go ahead or I'm of the wrong path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need an NS record on the zone hosted at DnsMadeEasy for *each* subdomain. This action is called "[delegating a subdomain](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/domain/create-delegate-a-subdomain/)" to an external DNS server. Here's the [DNS Made Easy guide](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/domain/create-delegate-a-subdomain/) for that.

For instance, you would need an NS record in the parent zone for: `tenant1.example.com`, which points to the *four* namserver addresses assigned to you when you create a `tenant1.example.com` hosted zone in Amazon Route 53.

Create your hosted subdomains in Amazon Route 53:

[image]

Then make sure DNS Made Easy has an entry like this for each subdomain:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (going through dnsmadeasy API for each account provisioning). Would adding a 4 part name solve this, eg. `tenant1.accounts.example.com` and delegate the entire `accounts.example.com` to Route53 work?

Comment: Yep. Delegate an entire subdomain, then add the sub-subdomains via Amazon's API/console. Or, could you just change the entire primary zone to Route 53?

Comment: I can change the entire primary to Route53, agree. I guess I was just trying to go the lazy route...